# Creating a geojson-vt and displaying in Leaflet 0.7

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a GEOJSON that I am loading up and displaying on a map using Leaflet it is, colour coding them depending on the abundance of the animal in an area and able to display a popup with more information.

What I have been trying to do is turn this into a vectorTile using geojson-vt and display this. This polygon geojson is one of the smaller and takes a long time to load and some others crash the browser.

I have tired to work through the example here http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/c67e5551b21c68dc8299 but I cannot understand what is happening.

I am definitely open to other ideas on how to display this data, I am very much a newbie.

If you wish to see what I have so far please look at http://huntingspots.co.nz/gareth/leaflet_layering.html.

Thank you very much for your time.

```
    //Pig Layer
    var pigLayer = new L.LayerGroup();
      $.getJSON("feralpig.geojson",function(hoodData){
      L.geoJson( hoodData, {
    style: function(feature){
        var fillColour,
            abundance = feature.properties.Abundance;
        if (abundance == "H") fillColour = "#194866";
        else if ( abundance == "M" ) fillColour = "#2c7eb2";
        else if ( abundance == "L" ) fillColour = "#40b5ff";
        else fillColour = "#f7f7f7";  // no data
      return { color: "#999", weight: 1, fillColor: fillColour, fillOpacity: .4 };
    },
    onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){
      layer.bindPopup( "<strong>" + "Species: " + "</strong>" + feature.properties.Scientific 
        + "<br/>" + "<strong>" + "Common Name: " + "</strong>" + feature.properties.CommonName
                + "<br/>" + "<strong>" + "Abundance: " + "</strong>" + feature.properties.Abundance 
                + "<br/>" + "<strong>" + "Data collection method: " + "</strong>" + feature.properties.AbundRelia 
        + "<br/>" + "<strong>" + "Notes: " + "</strong>" + feature.properties.AbundNotes);
    }
  }).addTo(pigLayer);
});
```

Comment: in which layer are those polygons?

Comment: the feralpig.geojson is added to a layer called pigLayer. the geojson is broken at the moment. My mate is working on getting the size down and something went wrong.